# Facebook comment into wordpress genisis

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

I am applying facebook comments to display on wordpress genisis theme on every post. I apply facebook comments on twentyeleven theme its work.
But failed to apply on genisis theme.
Can anyone help me how i can apply facebook comments to genisis theme .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

f you’re using the Genesis Theme Framework you can easily add a Facebook comment box to your single posts by adding the following code to your Functions.php file.

```
function add_fb_comments() {
    if (is_single()) { ?>
<h3>Comment With Facebook:</h3><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" num_posts="20" width="600">
</fb:comments>
    <?php }
}
add_action('genesis_after_post', 'add_fb_comments', '99');
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hello,I put that code with src="of my link" of i update function.php its not update and now gives error also site is not working give error.

Comment: but no i canot access admin here is the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/xxxx/wp-content/themes/genesis/functions.php on line 38

Comment: You need to login through the cPanel or ftp and then edit the functions.php

Comment: yes i edit through ftp and put the code as it is you sent me but the facebook comments box not displaying .